# Angular reactive form not returning decimal until another number is added

Tags: angular, typescript, reactive

When getting the value of the input field if I enter `45.` only `45` is returned until I add another number like `6` then `45.6` is returned. Anyone know a way around this or why this is happening?

```
<input [hidden]="decimal_allowed" [disabled]="decimal_allowed" 
formControlName="answer"  step="{{step}}" type="number" (keyup)="setAnswer()"
         [style.width]="width + 'px'" min="question.Min" max="question.Max">
```

That is the HTML the only thing in `setAnswer()` is `console.log(this.form_group.controls.get('answer').value);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`45.` is not a number, converted to a number it's just 45. If your input type was text you'd get `45.` as a string.

Answer (score 0):

As @funkizer rightly said that you cannot get `45.` with `number` as a type, but if you still want to detect when user types `.` then you can check for `keyCode` on `keyup`

```
<input type="number" (keyup)="setAnswer($event)>

setAnswer(event:any) {
  if(event.keyCode == '229') {
    // Handle '.' logic
  }
}
```